# react-native link realm fails

Tags: android, node.js, react-native, realm

I'm trying to get started working with react-native and I want to use realm as well. This is a brand new project here are my steps:

```
$ react-native init BibleBinderRN
$ cd BibleBinderRN/
$ react-native -v
```

At this point I see:

> react-native-cli: 2.0.1
>
> react-native: 0.45.1

Next:

```
$ npm install --save realm
$ react-native -v
```

Result:

`react-native-cli: 2.0.1`

`react-native: n/a - not inside a React Native project directory`

I don't understand why this is not an RN project directory at this point. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm relatively new on React Native however I got the same error the last days.
Indeed, when I installed different plugins with the command `npm install blabla --save`, just after I wasn't able to run command such as `react-native link ...` or even `react-native run-android`

After reading different topics, the solution I found was to do it with yarn. Indeed, with the command `yarn add blabla` it works perfectly. Some explanations I have found on github was about a problem of npm versions.

However, if you found a solution, I'm interest in !

Comment: This worked! I'd love to figure out an answer for nom but I guess it is just a bug. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First run:

```
npx react-native init name-project
```

Then install Realm:

```
npm install realm
```

Do not use CLI globally
https://reactnative.dev/docs/_getting-started-linux-android#installing-dependencies

Answer (score 0):

The previous comments do not mention how you correctly connect a setup react-native project with realm. **This is not trivial!** You'll find fast steps to setup a react-native app connected to realm here: [How do you setup Realm with React Native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67020431/how-do-you-setup-realm-with-react-native)

This will result in an example app which you can use as help to implement your own functionality.