# How do you setup Realm with React Native?

Tags: mongodb, react-native, realm, mongodb-atlas

## SOLVED

After having a lot of struggles here the fastest guide you'll ever find on how to setup a react native app with mongoDB realm. My thanks go to Joe who commented.

1. Setup the backend. Follow every step of the [backend tutorial](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/tutorial/realm-app/) very carefully. IMPORTANT: In Step E5, use your own name for the app instead of the default. **This name cannot be changed!**
2. Setup your app with `git clone --branch final https://github.com/mongodb-university/realm-tutorial-react-native.git`. Therby you skip the whole [frontend tutorial](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/tutorial/react-native/).
3. Remove the .git folder and rename the project root to complete your takeover.

Note that this example project contains backend functions and a lot of additional stuff on the frontend. Use those as cheat sheet for your implementations. Note that if you want to implement your backend functions using your IDE instead of in the online admincentral you need to do another [import](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/deploy/realm-cli-reference/#import-strategies) using realm-cli. Happy coding!

Comment: There are two complete guides for setting up Realm. One is the [Sync Data Tutorial](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/tutorial/react-native/) which it looks like you found. However, a lot of people overlook the [Set up the Back End Tutorial](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/tutorial/realm-app/#std-label-tutorial-task-tracker-create-realm-app) which helps you to configure the server.

Comment: I set the backend app up manually, as the tutorial is a bit too verbose and ponderous. Above the screenshot showing that my login is recognised on the backend. Do I need to take additional action on the collection like naming for example?

Comment: The tutorial is pretty accurate. I've walked through it several times and it clearly walks you through the specific steps to set up the back end. Without knowing what steps you went through, any answer would be shot in the dark. Please take a look at [https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/tutorial/realm-app/#set-up-the-task-tracker-tutorial-backend](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/tutorial/realm-app/#std-label-tutorial-task-tracker-create-realm-app) to set up the task tracker tutorial and compare it to your steps to see what was omitted or different.